# Pass value from one controller to another in angular js1

Tags: angularjs

I am using $rootScope for passing value from one controller to another but i did not get the value in second controller(cart).

```
    x.controller("first",function($scope,$http,$rootScope){
    $scope.cart1=function(x,y){
        $rootScope.img=x;
        $rootScope.login=y;
    }
    });
     x.controller("cart",function($scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.cart2=$rootScope.img;

    console.log($scope.cart2)
    });
```

Comment: when are you calling $scope.cart1? copy your whole code plz!!

Comment: the best way to pass value between controllers is via Service.

Comment: @ihappyk $rootScope is a service itself actually

Comment: try to inject that in controller. like (" first ",[ ' $rootScope' ],function ($rootScope)

Comment: @ihappyk Using `$rootScope` is not recommended and not considered as good practice. Your first suggestion to use service would be a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`$rootScope`** does not get the value assigned if you simply define in controller, you need to transfer the data from controller1 to controller2 based on some event

**DEMO**

```js
var x =angular.module('app', [])
 x.controller("first",function($scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.cart1=function(x,y){
        console.log(x);
        $rootScope.img=x;
        $rootScope.login=y;
    }
 });
 x.controller("cart",function($scope,$rootScope){
     
     $scope.getData=function(){
     $scope.cart2=$rootScope.img;
    console.log($scope.cart2)
    };
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
 <div ng-controller="first">
    <button ng-click="cart1('test','test2')">transfer</button>
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="cart">
 <button ng-click="getData()">getStoredValue</button>
  {{cart2}}
 </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE**
Using $rootScope is not a recommended way to transfer variable across controllers, instead try using **[`services`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338380/one-controller-two-view)**.

Comment: how to detect that the value have been shared? why don't use a event base approach like `$broadcast?`

Comment: I am asking you something technical, you are concerned about your down vote? and what about "`$rootScope does not get the value assigned if you simply define in controller`" ?? what does that meant? and also what if some other controller overrides that value that you shared in a service? and about downvote, how can you say that I have downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

why not using `$broadcast`, considering your controller structure `$scope.$parent` is enough, in oter case inject `$rootScope` from where you are firing the `$broadcast`

```
var x =angular.module('app', [])
 x.controller("first",function($scope){
    $scope.cart1=function(x,y){
        $scope.$parent.$broadcast('value changed', {x: X, y: y});
    }
 });
 x.controller("cart",function($scope){
    $scope.$on('value changed', function(data){
        $scope.login = x;
        $scope.cart2 = y;
    });         
 });
```

Now your values are set in scope, use it whenever needed (in case of binding it will automatically reflect in UI)

Answer (score 0):

```
   (function() {
    "use strict";

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory("cartFactory", cartFactory);

    function cartFactory($http) {
        return {
             login: '',
             cart2:''
        };
    }})();
```

This is your factory
you can use multiple  controller like this...

```
        var x =angular.module('app', [])
           x.controller("first",function($scope,cartFactory){
                cartFactory.login=x;
                cartFactory.cartFactory=y;


            }
      });



   x.controller("cart",function($scope,cartFactory){

       $scope.login = cartFactory.login;
       $scope.cart2 = cartFactory.cart2;

   });
```

This is very simple to pass data one controller to another multiple controller.